# Java/Android, Multiple Classes

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android and I have multiple classes.
I was wondering if there is a way that I could somehow include four classes in one major class.

Below is example of my code.
I am looking forward to help.

This is the FindUs class (major class)

```
package com.abc.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class FindUs extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.findUs);

            Button first = (Button) findViewById(R.id.first);
            Button second = (Button) findViewById(R.id.second);
            Button third = (Button) findViewById(R.id.third);
            Button fourth = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fourth);

            first.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.abc.example.FIRST"));
                }
            });

            second.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent("ccom.abc.example.SECOND"));
                }
            });

            third.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.abc.example.THIRD"));
                }
            });

            fourth.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    startActivity(new Intent("com.abc.example.FOURTH"));
                }
            });             
}
```

---

These are the minor classes (it makes sense only to post one).

```
package com.abc.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class First extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first);

    Button callFirst= (Button) findViewById(R.id.callfirst);
    Button mapFirst= (Button) findViewById(R.id.mapfirst);

    callFirst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String phoneNumber = "tel:+18000000000";
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneNumber));
            startActivity(callIntent);

        }
    });

    mapFirst.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String url = "grab google directions for this place";
            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,  Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(mapIntent);
                }
            });             
}
```

So you see, I will have different numbers and location for each class. So I am unsure if I should just keep the four individual classes or if I should include all four within one major class.

Thanks. Looking forward to learning more about this from your guys.

Comment: The `First` class doesn't look so minor to me. It's easily big enough to warrant sitting in its own file. Adding 4 of those as inner classes will not do your code readability much good.

Comment: I would keep them separate for clarity.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, you seem to be suggesting that you have four classes that are the same apart from a number and a location.

Comment: thank you very much for all your suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have every activity in a separate file.

If you have helper classes that that are only used in one activity you can use an inner class or put it below the other one (not public). **Activities should be separate files.**

What you could do is put code that has to be in the two classes also in a separate class so that both of them can use it.

Comment: Thanks. Like I stated, I am new to Java so I just wanted to make sure. First is not a minor class? Well now I know that.

Answer (score 0):

You should strive to keep the classes separate from each other while minimizing the amount of duplicate code.

If any class you write starts to grow too large, you should divide it to parts that focus around one concise idea and create relationships between the resulting classes by means of, for instance, [aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#Aggregation). In case the classes share some functionality and it seems you are writing duplicate code, you should consider isolating the common functionality into a superclass and derive the affected classes from there, *if* they all have an is-a relationship to the superclass.

Comment: do you think I need a superclass in my case?

Comment: They already have a superclass, `Activity`, but you are free to subclass it as you wish (because it is not final). It's your call.

Comment: okay, understand it now. like I said... I am new to this, so please do not get annoyed with my asking stupidness. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For sure you should keep activity classes in **separate** files.

Actually it is must to cause you need to put corresponding activity declaration in manifest file for all activities separately.

As @Maethortje said helper classes just for that activity can be below main class, in the same file, but if helper is used by more activities that one needs to be separate as well...

All this will make things easier for someone who is looking at your code later, but for you too when you decide to change, upgrade or improve application code.

Comment: cool. I can see why now. I see that it would be not as neat if I were to include all classes within a class. Right now, I have 12 classes, so it is pretty up there.