# Multiple Activites in one class on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I was wondering if instead of having to create a new class for each activity is it possible to create mulitiple activities within one class?

So define various layout xml for various activities within one class, instead of having to create new classes for each activity.

Thanks

Comment: If all your activities do the same thing, you can use setContextView(R.layout.whatever); multiple times to change your view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should put each activity in seperate class. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729904/java-android-multiple-classes/8729933#8729933) question. Someone is wondering just the same thing as you.

Answer (score 1):

Ricky,

Yes, you may have multiple "Activities" defined inside a single class. But there are a lot of obstacles and issues with doing so. Before I answer this question, two things must be understood:

1. What you are asking goes against the Android guidelines for development, and those guidelines are enforced in as many ways as they can be during the compilation process, so nothing I say here is insured to work across any or all API versions of the Android SDK.
2. Different development environments do their own checks and compile in slightly different ways. I will be speaking from the Eclipse side of development.
3. Techniques listed here are for education, but introduce a **lot** of issues. For self education and theory, it is a wonderful practice to explore. However, the goal of this answer is to educate you as to why the guideline should be followed rather than sidestepped.

**Requirements for an Activity**

The first thing to understand is that Android has specific points that must be met for an Activity to be run. It must: a) be declared in the manifest; b) have an intent-filter describing how it is to be used; c) be a public class; d) be a top-level class.

**Multiple Activities, Same Parent Class**

This means that you may create an Activity inside of another class (an inner Activity, so to speak), **but** it must be declared `static` and `public`. This limits your Activity in a huge number of ways. Calls to methods or members that are instance-related (not static) to the parent class are not possible. So you lose a lot of time and code hacking around this.

Second, it affects your Android XML declaration for your Activity. This is where the real trouble comes in, because while it can be done, it is very specific and there is not any supporting documentation to make that happen. But that's okay, you wanted to know if you could make ONE class for your Activities.

**Multiple Activities, Same Class**

Well, Android determines which Activity to run based on its Intent. You could declare the same class multiple times, but with different Names and Intent-filters. If this is the case, then you would have to determine what to do based on the Intent and the extras included. This would be done in your `onCreate()` method.

Doing things in this manner would mean that you would have to code for two Activities in *every* place that you would normally deal with one. This would make it much harder to track down bugs to support your product. It would also make every routine operation take longer as you would have to decide which method to perform. For instance, if you overrode onDraw(), you would have to know which Activity you were drawing. Its ultimately just a big schmorgasborg (sp? does *anyone* know how to spell that word?) of "what do I do?!"

**The Real Question**

Why would you want to do this anyway? 
1. If the answer is to save yourself time navigating your own project, believe me... That won't really happen. Your code will be harder to read, interpret and debug.

1. If the answer is that you want to save file space, I would reconsider your project's priorities.
2. If the answer is that you want to share functionality, consider extending Activity and then extending your new sub class. How do you think they made the ListActivity or TabActivity to begin with?
3. If you want to save state, you can place state in `SharedPreferences` or your `Application` object (if you have extended it).

As you can see, no matter your needs, there are many other ways to go about it in a way that doesn't cause you or anyone else a hassle.

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: There are situations where this is actually important, for instance where external constraints prevent the creation of additional Java classes, but multiple activities are required.  There is only one NativeActivity class. You mention that it is possible, could you elaborate on how to actually accomplish this instead of saying why it shouldn't be done?  I am trying to create a NativeActivity that can be invoked on multiple Activities.  Any ideas?